# cant access text field inside movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, textfield, movieclip

I have a movie clip symbol that I converted from a dynamic text field with the instance name "text2". When I try to add it as a child and then try to access the text field, the compiler throws:

Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

```
var test = new Qwe(); //Qwe is the movie clip converted from dynamic text field
addChild(test);

test.text2.text ="535";  //instance name of the text field was text2.
```

Answer (score 1):

The culprit was the "advanced layers" setting in Adobe Animate. Turning it off, solved the problem.